# Get model index inside ActiveDataProvider, Yii2

Tags: php, web, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I try to get my model position inside `dataProvider`.
I have a listview with pager:

```
 Pjax::begin();
                echo ListView::widget([
                    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                    'itemOptions' => ['class' => 'item'],
                    'itemView' => 'tree_part',

                    'pager' => [
                        'class' => ScrollPager::className(),
                         'enabledExtensions'=> [ScrollPager::EXTENSION_SPINNER],
                          'spinnerSrc'=> Yii::$app->request->baseUrl.'/images/spinner.gif',
                        ]
               ]);
Pjax::end();
```

I know i can access`$model, $widget, $index` in my partial view `tree_part.php`, but I cannot figure out how to get current `$model` index inside the data.

My dataprovider:

```
 $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([ 
        'query' => $query, 
        'sort'=> ['defaultOrder' => ['creation_date'=>SORT_DESC]],
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 12,
        ],
    ]);
```

So if the`pagesize` is 12, `$index` variable will only show the value of `0-11`. What I need is to get "global" index out of the total count of models.

Any advice would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:

```
 $mindex = $index + ($widget->dataProvider->pagination->pageSize * $widget->dataProvider->pagination->page);
```

Anyways, looking for better one.